# Does someone mind explaining to me the formatting to generate boards?

Tags: discussion

How do users use a board to make moves? I can't seem to figure out how.(On this program)

Comment: Check [this](http://meta.chess.stackexchange.com/questions/279/tool-used-to-create-chess-analysis-interactive-diagrams-in-many-chess-stack-exch/280#280) Meta Post.